# How to Store ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>InfoList data to SQLite Database in android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am getting all the data in `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>InfoList;` and this data I want to store in SQLite database locally which will be used later by the application.
All the data in `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>InfoList;` is coming from web server when the application starts. Please gudie me how to do the same. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to insert it as a single object, you can use the class ObjectMapper ( u can download jackson-all-1.9.0.jar to use it), to transform your object to String like this :

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String stringToAddOnSQLITE = writeValueAsString( your object here );
```

then you save it on the database as a string.
to transform the string to your object use this :

```
yourObject = mapper.readValue(stringToAddOnSQLITE , new TypeReference<YOUR OBJECT TYPE>() { });
```

Answer (score 0):

> To store object data in Sqlite

1: [Serialize your object](http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-serialization/)

2: [Store that object as BLOB Data in SQLITE](http://effbot.org/zone/sqlite-blob.htm)

> To retrieve object data from Sqlite

1: Get `blob` from `Sqlite` database

2: `DeSerialize` that `blob` in to your `object`

Comment: Thanks for the reply dhams. I'll try the way you have given.